# controller is Nil in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have following RSpec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe "Users", type: :request do  


  describe "sign in/out" do

    describe "success" do
      it "should sign a user in and out" do
        attr = {:name=>"Test1",
        :email => "dmishra@test.org",
        :password => "foobar",
        :password_confirmation => "foobar"
        }
        user = User.create(attr)
          visit signin_path
        fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
        fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
        puts page.body
        click_button "Sign in"
        controller.should be_signed_in
        click_link "Sign out"
        controller.should_not be_signed_in
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: controller.should be_signed_in
   expected  to respond to `signed_in?
```

This is because `controller` is `nil`. What is wrong here which causes `controller` to be `nil`?

Controller class is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end
  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

`signed_in` method is defined in session helper which is included.

Ruby platform information:
Ruby: 2.0.0p643
Rails: 4.2.1
RSpec: 3.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a request spec (which is basically a rails integration test) which is designed to span multiple requests, possibly across controllers.

The `controller` variable is set by the request methods that integration testing provides (`get`, `put`, `post` etc.)

If instead you use the capybara DSL (visit, click etc.) then the integration test methods never get called and accordingly `controller` will be nil. When using capybara you don't have access to individual controller instances so you can't test things such as what `signed_in?` returns - you have to test a higher level behaviour (e.g. what is on the page).

Comment: I moved this test case to controller test case.